# Javascript converts Number to undifined when trying to return a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, numbers, undefined

So I have the following function which converts an array to a list and works fine:

```
    function arrayToList (arr) {
      var list = null
      arr.reverse()
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        list = {value: arr[i], rest: list}
      }

      return list
    }
```

Now I'm trying to write a function which returns the nth value of the list

```
function nth (list, number) {
  if (number !== 0) {
    nth(list.rest, number - 1)
  } else {
    console.log(typeof list.value)
    return list.value
  }
}
```

if I run nth(list, 0) it works fine but when I change the index (number) to something else (e.g 1, 2, etc) in the function console.log shows that the type of list.value is Number but what it returns is undefined
P.S : I'm using node.js version 6.11.4 to run my code

Comment: It is because you pass then `list.rest` to the function `nth(list.rest, number - 1)`. It has no `.value`. You probably wnat to pass `nth(list, number - 1)`.

Comment: list.rest contains another list, and also if you print list.value it shows the value

Comment: Ah, yeah I missed that. You don't return on recursion. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` from intermediate calls as well

```
return nth(list.rest, number - 1) //observe that return before nth
```

i.e.

```
function nth (list, number) {
  if (number !== 0) {
    return nth(list.rest, number - 1);
  } else {
    console.log(typeof list.value)
    return list.value;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var list = null
  arr.reverse()
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    list = {
      value: arr[i],
      rest: list
    }
  }

  return list
}

function nth (list, number) {
  if (number !== 0) {
    return nth(list.rest, number - 1);
  } else {
    //console.log(typeof list.value)
    return list.value;
  }
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var list = arrayToList(arr);
console.log(nth(list,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your if condition -

```
return nth(list.rest, number - 1)
```

Or just use this in your else condition instead of returning a value -

```
console.log(list.value);
```

use it as per your use case.